# Cassandra MemTable Flush

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What I understood about Cassandra Memtable flush is whenever 33% of memtable heap+offheap space is consumed, cassandra flush writer starts flushing the largest memtable. In that case there could be situation where few smaller memtables where not much of writes are happening would lie on the memory. What would happen to those memtables? When are those memtables are going to be flushed.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways AFAIK.

1. `memtable_cleanup_threshold` as you described.
2. `memtable_flush_period_in_ms` per table prop which defines the periodic flush period.
3. `nodetool flush` and `nodetool drain`. (`drain` stops listening for new requests)

Comment: also flush happens when commitlog segments need to be reclaimed, and when streams need to be sent, and when repair is running